# Display a LangChain chart in a streamlit app using ChatGPT

Tags: python, streamlit, openai-api, langchain, chatgpt-api

I am trying to convert the following [notebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython#Project_Jupyter) to a streamlit app: https://github.com/Isaakkamau/Data_Analysis_Cohort2/blob/main/Manu_Data_analysis_with_AI.ipynb

The app is working fine, except that no visualizations are displayed.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import os
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
from langchain.agents import create_csv_agent
from langchain.llms import OpenAI


def initialize_agent(openai_api_key, csv_path, verbose=False):
    agent = create_csv_agent(OpenAI(temperature=0, openai_api_key=openai_api_key), csv_path, verbose=verbose)
    return agent


def main():
    st.set_page_config(page_title="LangChain Streamlit App")
    st.title("LangChain Streamlit App")

    # Get OpenAI API key from user input in the sidebar
    openai_api_key = st.sidebar.text_input("OpenAI API Key", type="password")
    if not openai_api_key:
        st.info("Please add your OpenAI API key to continue.")
        st.stop()

    # Get the CSV file from user upload
    uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Upload CSV file", type=["csv"])
    if not uploaded_file:
        st.info("Please upload a CSV file to continue.")
        st.stop()

    # Read the CSV file into a pandas DataFrame
    df = pd.read_csv(uploaded_file)

    # Display the first few rows of the DataFrame
    st.write("Uploaded CSV file:")
    st.dataframe(df.head())

    # Save the DataFrame as a temporary CSV file
    temp_csv_path = "temp.csv"
    df.to_csv(temp_csv_path, index=False)


    agent = initialize_agent(openai_api_key, temp_csv_path)

    # Get user query
    user_query = st.text_input("Ask me anything:")

    if user_query:
        # Run the LangChain agent with the user query
        response = agent.run(user_query)
        st.write("Response:")
        st.write(response)


    # Remove the temporary CSV file
    os.remove(temp_csv_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I was expecting a bar graph in the streamlit app like the way it has been displayed in [Jupyter Notebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython#Project_Jupyter).

Comment: Isn't there supposed to be two images? 'lCaSf.png' does not seem to render.